# Delete Perspective manually

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I want to delete perspectives which I have created. But here I don't want to use Eclipse's own page. I want to create my own page and display list of Perspectives and give option to delete it or make it default. I don't want to use default Eclipse page because I don't need "Fast View" and other options for perspectives. That's why I decided to create my own page list only what I need. But I don't know how to get list of perspectives and methods to make it default and delete.

This the page which I am displaying right now in my application:
[image: Click here to open perspective page]

Comment: The lower side of the page isn't enough for the purpose?

Comment: Lower portion only i need. Upper portion I don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `IPerspectiveRegistry` to manipulate the perspective registry:

```java
IPerspectiveRegistry perspectiveRegistry = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry();
```

You can get the list of perspectives from the registry with:

```java
IPerspectiveDescriptor [] perspectives = perspectiveRegistry.getPerspectives();
```

You can delete a perspective by calling the registry method

```java
public void deletePerspective(IPerspectiveDescriptor persp)
```

but note that the JavaDoc says:

> Deletes a perspective. Has no effect if the perspective is defined in
>   an extension.

Comment: How to get "persp" from selected perspective ID or Label ?

Comment: `IPerspectiveRegistry` has a `findPerspectiveWithId` method.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I got list and deletion is also done. Now I am looking for same "List" box as there is in above picture but I can't find such list in design palette. I could see combo but List seems good to display perspective. Could you please assist how to display List box for available perspectives ?

Comment: Looks like a `TableViewer` but this is a new question.